# Is it safe to use if like this?

Tags: bash

I have a program that reads from the terminal, and then compares it with several numbers, like:

```
read input
if [ $input == 5 ]
then
  echo "The number is 5"
fi
if [ $input == 42 ]
then
  echo "The number is 42"
fi
```

Note that I didn't use quotes when I wrote this.
I can't change this code unless it's absolutely sure it's not safe.
The only thing I saw is that if `$input` contains of 2 or more words, it drops an error to stderr, and gets into the else. However, this fortunately doesn't break the code.
So, is this safe? (I mean that a command specified by the input can't be executed)  If it isn't, please attach code.

**EDIT:** I know that we use `-eq` and `[[...]]`, but when I wrote this, I just didn't care. The problem is that it would be very hard to change this piece of code, and if this can execute some commands (and maybe redirect the output to stdout or stderr), then it will be a big problem, but if it isn't so bad, I don't change this code, no matter how ugly it is.

Comment: You are missing the `fi` to close `if`. Also, to compare integers we don't use `=` but `-eq`.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking here. The code you have posted clearly doesn't represent the actual code that you're working with. It sounds like you know it's broken but you don't want to fix it and you want us to tell you it's OK!

Comment: The code is hard to fix (I must be at the server physically to change the code, which is far far away, long story). But if there is no way to exploit this ugly code, it isn't broken. It's just ugly. However, if it was truly broken, the fix would take long, and I would have to shut down the server, so it's very inconvinient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No command can be run from $input. I can't find it in the documentation, but it seems command (and redirection) boundaries are parsed from the command line before any expansions happen. Cf.

```
x='echo a ; echo b'
$x
```

Output:

```
a ; echo b
```

Or (no tilde expansion)

```
x='ls ~'
$x
```

Returns:

```
ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory
```

The same applies to redirections (try `x='ls | grep .'`).

Answer (score 1):

`if [ $input == 5 ]` is bad for a couple of reasons. Using `==` is a non-standard way of comparing two **strings** (the more standard approach is to use a single `=`). If you want to compare two **integers**, you should use `if [ "$input" -eq 5 ]` instead. The double quotes around the variable prevent word splitting.

If you want to take advantage of Bash-specific features, you can use one of the following:

```
if [[ $input -eq 5 ]] # no need for quotes inside `[[`
```

or

```
if (( input == 5 )) # arithmetic context
```

Answer (score 0):

Relatively safes approach that won't generate stated error is using `[[` and `]]` and use `==` to compare like this:

```
read -p "Enter value: " input

if [[ $input == 5 ]]; then
  echo "The number is 5"
elif [[ $input == 42 ]]; then
  echo "The number is 42"
fi
```

This won't generate error even if you enter 2 string words in `input` variable.

For more details run `help [[` in your terminal.